# Unitils database exception

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, unitils

In my project I am using JDBC, MySQL, Servlets, JSP.
To test my dao's i made some unit tests and i am trying to use JUnit and Unitils.

I am getting this exception:

```
    org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error inserting test data from DbUnit dataset for method public void com.jean.taxi.daoImpl.ClientDaoImplTest.testListModerators()
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:190)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule$DbUnitListener.beforeTestSetUp(DbUnitModule.java:791)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:181)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:59)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:67)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1385)
    at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1414)
    at org.unitils.core.dbsupport.MySqlDbSupport.toCorrectCaseIdentifier(MySqlDbSupport.java:189)
    at org.unitils.core.dbsupport.DbSupport.init(DbSupport.java:97)
    at org.unitils.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.getDbSupport(DbSupportFactory.java:77)
    at org.unitils.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.getDefaultDbSupport(DbSupportFactory.java:56)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.getDefaultDbSupport(DbUnitModule.java:755)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.getDataSetFactory(DbUnitModule.java:725)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.getDataSetFactory(DbUnitModule.java:713)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.getDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:441)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:261)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:187)
    ... 21 more
```

My unitils-local.propreties:

```
database.userName=root
database.password=111111
database.storedIndentifierCase.mysql=mixed_case
dbUnit.datasetresolver.prefixWithPackageName=false
database.identifierQuoteString.mysql=none
database.schemaNames=TEST
database.dialect=mysql
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

My unitils.properties:

```
# Name or path of the user specific properties file. This file should contain the necessary parameters to connect to the
# developer's own unit test schema. It is recommended to override the name of this file in the project specific properties
# file, to include the name of the project. The system will try to find this file in the classpath, the user home folder
# (recommended) or the local filesystem.
unitils.configuration.localFileName=unitils-local.properties

# Properties for the PropertiesDataSourceFactory
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

database.schemaNames=test
# This property specifies the underlying DBMS implementation. Supported values are 'oracle', 'db2', 'mysql' and 'hsqldb'.
# The value of this property defines which vendor specific implementations of DbSupport and ConstraintsDisabler are chosen.
dbUnit.datasetresolver.prefixWithPackageName=false
```

My dataset options:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CLIENT ID="1" CLIENT_NAME="clientName" CLIENT_LAST_NAME="clientLastName"
            EMAIL="email" ADDRESS="address" PASSWORD="password"
            PHONE="phone" SECOND_PHONE="secondPhone" THIRD_PHONE="thirdPhone" CREATE_DATE="2015-10-05 08:35:25"/>
    <CLIENT_GRANT ID="1" ID_CLIENT="1" ADMIN="0" MODERATOR="0" ACTIVE="1"/>
</dataset>
```

And some part of my test-dao class, which i am trying to test:

```
@Transactional(TransactionMode.ROLLBACK)
@DataSet("ClientDaoImplTest.xml")
public class ClientDaoImplTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {
    @TestDataSource
    DataSource dataSource;

    ClientDaoImpl clientDao = null;
    ClientGrantDaoImpl clientGrantDao = null;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        clientDao = new ClientDaoImpl(dataSource);
        clientGrantDao = new ClientGrantDaoImpl(dataSource);
        TransactionHandlerImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        clientDao.setCurrentLocalConnection(ConnectionHolder.getLocalConnection());
        clientGrantDao.setCurrentLocalConnection(ConnectionHolder.getLocalConnection());
    }

    @After
    public void destroy() {
        clientDao = null;
        clientGrantDao = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNew() {
        final User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("email");
        user.setAddress("address");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setClientName("clientName");
        user.setClientLastName("clientLastName");
        user.setPhone("phone");
        final ClientGrant clientGrant = user.getClientGrant();
        clientGrant.setClientId(user.getId());
        clientGrant.setActive(true);
        user.setClientGrant(clientGrant);
        executeTest(new Transaction<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void doTransaction() throws Exception {
                Long clientId = clientDao.addNew(user);
                user.setId(clientId);
                clientGrantDao.addNew(user.getClientGrant());
                assertTrue(assertClient(clientDao.get(clientId), user));
            }
        });
    }
```

I know that something wrong with my database options.
Can you help me to find the way how to fix this issue?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** after changing the parameter in my unitils-local.properties:
from:

```
database.identifierQuoteString.mysql=none
```

to:

```
database.identifierQuoteString.mysql=auto
```

a had a new exception:

```
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error inserting test data from DbUnit dataset for method public void com.jean.taxi.daoImpl.ClientDaoImplTest.testAddNew()
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:190)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule$DbUnitListener.beforeTestSetUp(DbUnitModule.java:791)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:181)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:59)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:67)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error while executing DataSetLoadStrategy
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:46)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:342)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:268)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:187)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: client.ID -  (Non-uppercase input column: ID) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:117)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractOperation.getOperationMetaData(AbstractOperation.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:143)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.CleanInsertLoadStrategy.doExecute(CleanInsertLoadStrategy.java:45)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:44)
    ... 24 more
```

Maybe there is some new variants or some thoughts about that issue? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Unitils are you using?  That exception message suggests to me a discrepancy between the core and dbunit 'modules' of Unitils.

Comment: Hi Luke. I am using Unitils Version 3.4.2.

Comment: I see you've since updated your question and replaced the stacktrace, so my comment no longer fits with your question.  For the benefit of someone else who may have the same problem as you, how did you fix this?

Comment: I am sorry for this... But after that issue - i had a lot of new issues... Which are very similar.
In my first issue(first edit): was the problem with database url.
I used "database.url=jdbc:mysql:thin:@localhost:3306:test". But for MySQL it isn't correct.
And i changed it to:
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the problem is here:

```
database.identifierQuoteString.mysql=none
```

Try setting it to the following instead:

```
database.identifierQuoteString.mysql=auto
```

Ultimately the class MySqlDbSupport has a bug in it.  If the `database.identifierQuoteString.mysql` property is set to `none` in the properties file, a private field named `identifierQuoteString` in the class DbSupport is set to null.  The `toCorrectCaseIdentifier` method in MySqlDbSupport fetches the value of this field, but forgets to do a null-check before passing it to `String.startsWith`.  Hence we get a NullPointerException.

Using `auto` asks the database for the identifier-quote string to use.  I don't see why you would want to use anything other than this.

Comment: Hi Luke) You are the only one person who trying to help. Thanks. I had used your advice in my unitils-local.properties.
I had updated my question, if you had some time just look at the updated last part of question. Maybe you know something about this problem.

Comment: @davakin111: to be honest, I don't know anything much about Unitils (I've never used it myself) other than it appears to have been more-or-less abandoned in 2011.  I based my answer on reading the source code of Unitils.  The exception you mention in your most recent edit comes from within DbUnit, which I haven't used either. Sorry, I don't think I can help you any more here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.That's ok :)
Did you know some frameworks for database testing, something very similar to Unitils?

Comment: @davakin111: sorry, no I don't.

Comment: @davakin111 some time passed, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34659291/1037316) might be what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, already solved this issue... and only by changing database-testing framework :)

 I find much info in the documentation and it is the official bug, which isn't fixed, and never will be...

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue when using unitils with a MySQL DB. 
The solution is to configure a MySQL metadata handler :

```
org.dbunit.database.IMetadataHandler.implClassName=org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlMetadataHandler
```

I know that issue is old and unitils is no longer maintained but it can help someone.

Comment: Thank you so much! In last 2 day I have spent so much time on this issue!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution is add this line to the properties:

```
unitils.module.dbunit.className=org.dbunit.MySqlDbUnitModule
```